# How to process an incoming sms/mms with picture with twill

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have create a simple app to receive incoming sms and forward as to an email address.  Everything works great until I add a picture taken from my phone to the message.

How can I process an incoming message containing a picture?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about whats not working?  Are you seeing a specific error?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything.  Nothing even makes it to the logs in Twilio.  I see my regular texts but with my tests with an image, there is nothing.  No reply no log entry.

Comment: What country are the phone numbers you are sending to and from?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately today MMS is only supported on Canadian 10 digit phone numbers.  MMS is only available in the US on short codes.  We are working hard to make MMS available globally.

Hope that helps.